# MySQL procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have made an update query to mark one of the duplicate entry as FAILURE (Duplicate entries are there) by comparing there IDs(primary Key) but there are more then two duplicates entries coming and also all of them are updating as FAILURE only.Please help me out here. Here is my update query :

```
UPDATE P20_Extract_Invoice n1,
       P20_Extract_Invoice n2
SET n1.Closure_Status = 'FAILURE',
    n1.Failure_Reason = 'DUPLICATE_ENTRY'
WHERE n1.WorkItemID = n2.WorkItemID
  AND n1.ID != n2.ID
  AND n1.Closure_Status = 'PICKED_FOR_PROCESSING'
  AND n2.Closure_Status = 'PICKED_FOR_PROCESSING';
```

Comment: *FYI:* An `UPDATE` *statement* is not a *query*. The `SELECT` statement is a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rows with `ID` 7 and 8 are duplicate, the cross-join done by the update statement will compare `ID=7` vs `ID=8`, but also `ID=8` vs `ID=7`, so both are updated.

*You* need to decide which of the two you want to keep.

E.g. to keep the one with the smallest `ID`, change to `n1.ID > n2.ID`, i.e. update the one with the higher `ID` value.